# Return the sorted index of values above a certain probability in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of probabilities, and I want to keep only the index of the values above 0.5, and sort these index values according to the probability.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(10)
```

```
array([0.04620414, 0.0534432 , 0.04707483, 0.83529697, 0.24629344,
       0.58690842, 0.71345104, 0.02997366, 0.73212914, 0.99201534])
```

From the values above 0.5, I want the sorted indices, so:

```
[9, 3, 8, 6, 5]
```

I think it's going to be a combination of `np.argwhere()` and `arr[arr > 0.5]` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (sorted([index for index in range(10) if arr[index] > 0.5], key=lambda index: arr[index]))
```

This gives a python list. This works because the `[index for ... if arr[index] > 0.5]` is a list comprehension that returns the indexes which their values are > 0.5, and the `key` defines the value you want to sort based on (the actual value of `arr[index]` instead of index itself)

Also after researching on some numpy stuff, I think this will work as well

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.2, 0.8, 0.6])

print ([index for index in np.argsort(x) if index in np.where(x > 0.5)[0]]) # [2, 1]
```

Replace `x` with your random array

And finally I realise you wanted descending order while both of my codes are in ascending order haha

Comment: Or you can use `np.where` as mentioned

Comment: I added a numpy solution if that helps. Basically the exact same thing, (ab)using that python list comprehension goes through the iterator in order

Answer (score 1):

This should be working. Basically I execute the `np.where` on an already sorted list for which I remember the order (thanks to `argsort`), and I re-apply that order to the indices found to get the final `where_in_order` which is variable you're after.

```
import numpy as np

# arr = np.random.rand(10)
arr = np.array([0.04620414, 0.0534432 , 0.04707483, 0.83529697, 0.24629344,
       0.58690842, 0.71345104, 0.02997366, 0.73212914, 0.99201534])
print("original:")
print(arr)
print()

order = arr.argsort()
print("sorted:")
print(arr[order])
print()

print("where above 0.5 in increasing order:")
where_idx = np.where(arr[order] > 0.5)
print("found:")
print(arr[order][where_idx])
print()

print("found in order:")
where_in_order = order[where_idx]
print(arr[where_in_order])

print("decreasing order indices:")
print(list(reversed(where_in_order)))
```

yields

```
original:
[0.04620414 0.0534432  0.04707483 0.83529697 0.24629344 0.58690842
 0.71345104 0.02997366 0.73212914 0.99201534]

sorted:
[0.02997366 0.04620414 0.04707483 0.0534432  0.24629344 0.58690842
 0.71345104 0.73212914 0.83529697 0.99201534]

where above 0.5 in increasing order:
found:
[0.58690842 0.71345104 0.73212914 0.83529697 0.99201534]

found in order:
[0.58690842 0.71345104 0.73212914 0.83529697 0.99201534]
decreasing order indices:
[9, 3, 8, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Not your fault, the original example he gave was wrong

Comment: The original example I gave had the misfortune of being sorted already. It was an odd coincidence. The sorted probability indices were correctly returned without sorting.

Comment: @NicolasGervais I edited my post, it should be ok now. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is exactly what you're looking for:

```py
np.where(arr>0.5)
```

Output:

```
(array([0, 2, 6]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a list, you can filter and sort in a simple way:

```
arr_filtered = filter(lambda x: x > 0.5, arr)
arr_filtered.sort()
print (arr_filtered)
```

If you want reverse order:

```
arr_filtered.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: filter has no attribute sort?

Comment: I'm afraid not: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: what i'm trying to say is that this is the error i'm getting